# Rendering view after changing Locale by Ajax in Symfony 4

Tags: php, ajax, locale, symfony4

I am trying to change page language by a dropdown. Dropdown is generated by this code `{{ form_widget(registrationForm.locale, { 'attr': {'onChange': 'languageChange()'} }) }}` in the twig.

### Ajax function

```
function languageChange() {
    let selectedLanguage = $('#email_form_locale').val();
    $.ajax({
        url:        '{{ path('change_locale') }}',
        type:       'POST',
        dataType:   'json',
        data:       {'selectedLanguage': selectedLanguage},
        async:      true,

        success: function(data, status) {
            console.info(data);
            location.reload();
        },
        error : function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('Ajax request failed.');
        }
    });

}
```

### Controller function

```
/**
         * @Route("/registration/changeLocale", name="change_locale")
         * Method({"GET","POST"})
         */
        public function changeLocale (Request $request)
        {
            $user = new User();

            $form = $this->createForm(EmailFormType::class, $user);

            if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
                $jsonData = array();
                $temp = $request->request->all();
                $jsonData[0] = $temp;
                $request->getSession()->set('_locale', $temp['selectedLanguage']);
                $request->setLocale($temp['selectedLanguage']);
                $jsonData[1] = $request->getLocale();
                $user->setLocale($temp['selectedLanguage']);
                return new JsonResponse(array(
                        'jsonData' => $jsonData,
                        'html' => $this->renderView('main/registration.html.twig', array('registrationForm' => $form->createView()))
                    )
                );
            } else {
                return $this->render('main/registration.html.twig');
            }
```

I am trying to render the view after Jason response. Then the page must be selected languge( I have added the translation module and words for certain languages in translation folder and If I change the locale in services.yaml languages are changing)
Please help me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that's what you look for ?
https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation/locale.html

If you follow what's explained here, it should set the Locale for the whole Translation component during that request. So all your translated labels will change.